# How to use Parse to send/receive data types

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, server, cloud

My goal is to while using parse as a backend for both Android & iOS. I need to be able to send data types, and do something based on the data itself.

I don't fully understand how to implement cloud code, which i think would really help my situation.

Basically I am as a user logged in, will request a time/date(Already have that solved) the request is in the form of a string.

I need that string to be sent to the server, from the server be emailed and or sent as a data type to be used in either a website or desktop application.

How can I do this? Where can I learn about using cloud code, in certain examples?

Thanks.

Comment: The documentation on the subject is rather good, so think you just need to dive into it. They have great ways of integrating with sendgrid and mandril for instance.

Comment: I have dove into it. I don't understand what send grid is, or mandril? Sorry, I usually have to ask a few questions before I can understand it.

Comment: I looked up send grid looks like that could potentially work for what I need to do for this. However, what I am trying to understand is how I can send information to a server and have the server do something based on what the data type is, and what that data type consists of.

Comment: The communication part is covered by the cloud code documentation. Regarding the data type, you haven't been very specific until now but you should be able to look at properties of the data, e.g. Does it contain x, or y etc.